# How to connect VPN Site to vHub on Azure vWAN?

Tags: azure, azure-vpn

I am using Azure vWAN and secured vHub.  I created a VPN Site named "onprem-site" containing a link named "onprem-link" to an on-premise VPN solution.  The VPN tunnel was working correctly. Today the VPN Site lost its connection to the vHub.  (Note: I believe I accidentally deleted the connection, but I'm not sure what happened)

I want to re-connect the VPN Site with the vHub.  How can I perform this task?

In Azure Portal, **Home > Virtual WANSs > vwan_name > vhub_name**

Click on VPN (Site to site)

Under VPN Sites, "onprem-site" is not listed

The options in Portal include 'Download VPN Config', 'Delete gateway', 'Reset gateway', 'Create new VPN site'

I do not see a way to connect to vhub.

In Azure Portal, **Home > Virtual WANSs > vwan_name**

Click on VPN Sites

"onprem-site" is listed. Provisioning status shows "Provisioned". Hub shows "Connection needed".
Click on "onprem-site"

Connected Hubs shows "No results"

Links shows "onprem-link"

The options in Portal include 'Edit site' and Add link'.  Neither of these options let me connect to vhub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was caused by me not seeing a "filter" in the Azure UI.

In Azure Portal, **Home > Virtual WANSs > vwan_name > vhub_name**

Click on VPN (Site to site)

Notice the light blue highlighted text "Hub association : **Connected to this hub** X

Click on the X to show ALL Sites.

Now you have access to a button labeled Connect VPN sites.